# MySQL prepared statement using IN

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

I want to execute a prepared statement like

```
prepare stmt1 from 'select * from tags where name in (?)'

set @a='tag1, tag2' ;

execute stmt1 using @a ;
```

But alas, it does not work as expected (it seems to treat the argument to `in` as a single string).

Is it possible to form a list like this using `in` in a prepared statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, no.

THe basic query that you're telling to to try to run is `select * from foo where bar in ('tag1, tag2')`, which means it's matching the *string* `'tag1, tag2'` and not treating it as a list.

Unfortunately, with `in`, you typically need to do dynamic queries.  Other options are a UDF which parse out the string, or a temp table you join against.

Comment: Ok, hold on. How do you parse the string in a user defined function?  You can't just run an `exec` type statement on the list and have it work can you?

Answer (score 1):

No. You can build the SQL dynamically (using for example CONCAT) and then execute it.

Or you can use multiple parameters:

```
prepare stmt1 from 'select * from tags where name in (?, ?)'

set @a='tag1';
set @b='tag2';

execute stmt1 using @a, @b;
```